# How to pick element inside iframe using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, getelementbyid, frameset

I have a `iframe` like this

```
<iframe name="myframe1" id="myframe1" width="100%" height="100%" src="a.html">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <frameset name="myframe2" cols="0%, 100%" border="0" frameBorder="0" frameSpacing="0">
        <frame name="page1" src="c.html" scrolling="no"></frame>
        <frame name="page2" src="d.html" >
            <html>
                <head></head>
                <body id="top">
                    <div id="div1">
                        <div id="div2">
                            <div id="div3">
                                <ul id="x">
                                    <li>a</li>
                                    <li>b</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>

        </frame>

    </frameset>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I want to refer to the element "x". I tried in several ways but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('myframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById('x')
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfRYQ/)

[`contentWindow`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljctglqj.php) is supported by all browsers including the older versions of IE.

Note that if the `iframe`'s `src` is from another domain, you won't be able to access its content due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: The last sentence is very important ;) you frame's source must be on the same domain of your page

Comment: But what if frame's source not belongs to the same domain ? How to solve it? Regards, Mik.

Answer (score 25):

use [`contentDocument`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp) to achieve this

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) 
               ? iframe.contentDocument 
               : iframe.contentWindow.document;

var ulObj = innerDoc.getElementById("ID_TO_SEARCH");
```

Answer (score 8):

(this is to add to the chosen answer)

Make sure the `iframe` is loaded before you

```
contentWindow.document
```

Otherwise, your `getElementById` will be `null`.

PS: Can't comment, still low reputation to comment, but this is a follow-up on the chosen answer as I've spent some good debugging time trying to figure out I should force the `iframe` load before selecting the inner-iframe element.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the frame is fully loaded
the best way to do it is to use onload:

```
<iframe id="nesgt" src="" onload="custom()"></iframe>

function custom(){
    document.getElementById("nesgt").contentWindow.document;
    }
```

this function will run automatically when the iframe is fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to grab **pdfTron** toolbar, but unfortunately its **ID** changes every-time you refresh the page.

So, I ended up grabbing it with this one-liner:

`const pdfToolbar = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('HeaderItems');`

As in the array written by tagName you will always have the fixed index for iFrames in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies I don't have enough reputations to add a comment but maybe writing an answer is ok in this case.  I've been looking to change the css of some html in an Iframe.  I have a bookmarklet code which works outside an iframe so I'm nearly there:

```
javascript:(function(){ var style = document.createElement('style'), styleContent = document.createTextNode('.notifications-list--cMVsqVbKkaXV4SQ {zoom: 0.8!important;}'); style.appendChild(styleContent); var caput = document.getElementsByTagName('head'); caput[0].appendChild(style); })();
```

my iframe is called `xm-feed-iframe`

so I guessed you'd change the code to

```
document.getElementById('xm-feed-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('x')
```

But I needed to work with a class in order to change the css styles.  So I guess it might be as simple as changing

```
var caput = document.getElementsByTagName('head')
```

to

```
var caput = document.getElementById('xm-feed-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')
```

so the final code would be

```
javascript:(function(){ var style = document.createElement('style'), styleContent = document.createTextNode('.notifications-list--cMVsqVbKkaXV4SQ {zoom: 0.8!important;}'); style.appendChild(styleContent); var caput = document.getElementById('xm-feed-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head'); caput[0].appendChild(style); })();
```

And hey presto it worked.  I can now delve a little deeper and add some counters hopefully to the list which appears in the iframe! :)

Any comments about the code would be most appreciated as I'm self taught!

Hope this helps someone else

Thanks

UPDATE:
Here we are - I know have a numbered list using a bookmarklet.  My life will be so much easier now as I will no longer loss track of all the items I need to download. :D

[image]