# getElementById from another page

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, fitnesse

I am trying to get one `div` from one webpage URL to another webpage and display in plain text using `getElementById` without using AJAX or jQuery because I'm going to implement it in FitNesse. Is there a way to pass the URL?

Comment: You can do it with AJAX if that other page is in your domain. Otherwise JSONP or simply a line of PHP might help.

Comment: Not without making any external requests like ajax

Comment: Is the pages on the same domain? Otherwise, you might run into some nasty CORS-errors (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: yes it is on the same domain

Comment: Can we get some of your code so that we can help you _improve_ it.

Answer (score 8):

You could load the URL in a hidden iframe.

Then use iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById($id) as outlined here: [How to pick element inside iframe using document.getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid)

Something along the lines of:

```
<iframe src="urlWithinYourDomain.html" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Followed by a function something like:

```
var divElement = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.getElementById('elementIdOnSourcePage');
document.getElementById('targetParentId').appendChild(divElement);
```

I'm afraid I can't test this at the moment, so there may be syntax errors, but I think it conveys the idea. It's a bit of a dirty approach, but given your constraints it's the best way I can see to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

On page 1.

```
<div id="dataDiv">1234</div>
<a id="getData" href="">Page2</a>

<script>
var data = document.getElementById('dataDiv').innerHTML;
//This will get the content from the div above with the id of "dataDiv"

document.getElementById("getData").setAttribute("href","page2.html?var="+data);
//This will set the url of the anchor with the id of "getData" with your url and the passing data.
</script>
```

And on page 2

```
  function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
  }
  var var1 = getUrlVars()["var"];
```

This will send the content in your div on page one to page two.  the result url on page 1 will be page2.html?var=1234

Comment: Edited.  If your only passing a few numbers, this is a pretty simple way of doing it.

Comment: Adam, what you script does is: setting the whole element's HTML inside a link that after you press you'll navigate to some other page and only on that other page you'll than read the ["var"] String Query. **That has nothing to do with scraping content (from an Element ID) from an external page**.

Comment: Is he not trying to take the content of a div on page one, and pass it to page2?  I just tested my code and it does exactly this.  Unless i am misunderstanding the question.