# interpret the html code from clipboard and paste it into html view format

Tags: javascript, html, css, clipboard

I have some html code, for example,

`<div><span style="background:yellowgreen">name:</span><span>Rose</span></div>`,

I want to copy and paste the code into rich text format, which can resolve the html code into real DOM.

I know that there is js clipBoardData, zeroClipBoard, clipBoard-polyfill, but they all have a compatibility problem. I want to write one, which can work for most browsers, how can I do this? some idea?

In my mind, each browser can resolve `html` code, and the stuff I copied also written in `html`, when I paste it in someplace, such as `textarea` in some website, the browser can interpret the stuff and display it. But how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do by simply setting the `innerHTML` of your desired element with the value of the `textarea`.

As for having a nice text editor to do this in the browser. Check out https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor.

```js
const buttonElement = document.getElementById("submit");
const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
const outputElement = document.getElementById("output");

buttonElement.onclick = function() {
    output.innerHTML = inputElement.value;
};

buttonElement.click();
```

```css
#output {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input"><h1>test</h1></textarea>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: this is help! Thank you! but how i do this, if the output area is another page? I copy <h1>test</h1> to my clipboard, then past it into my email(output page), I want to see it interpret <h1>test</h1> into html view(large and bold fonts)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the rich text editors. [Here](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/) you can see most advanced rich text editors.

```
clipboard.setData('text/plain', selection.getText());
clipboard.setData('application/officeObj’, selection.serialize());
clipboard.setData('image/bmp', draw(selection));
clipboard.setData('text/html', '<div><span style="background:yellowgreen">name:</span><span>Rose</span></div>');
```

This is javascript code which helps you to copy some text with type such as `text/plain` , `text/html` etc. you will need `text/html`

Your question is if this code is compatible in every browsers? right?
As I see [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) this type of clipboarevent is compatible in modern browsers.

Good luck. If my answer helps you please please rate it as helpful

Answer (score 0):

[Check if HTML snippet is valid with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026626/check-if-html-snippet-is-valid-with-javascript) - based on this I "validate" the html but I don't know if it's necessary to you, if you want or not to have just the output to be correct (even if the html string you paste is not 100% correct). If you want only the output to be correct then Devan's answer is the most simple

```js
function tidy(html) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = html;
    return d.innerHTML;
}

function print(){
    //get input from textbox
    var htmlInputValue = document.getElementById("htmlInput").value;
    // "validate" as html
    var result = tidy(htmlInputValue);
    //print it
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}

var myInput  = document.getElementById("htmlInput");
myInput.addEventListener("input", print, false);
```

```css
#result {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <label for="input">Enter your html here </label>
    <input class="myInput" id="htmlInput" value="">

    <p id="result"/> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: i added some css for bold and large text
    #result { font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold }

Comment: hello but if the id="result" area is another page, how do i do this? e.g. I copy <h1>test</h1> to my clipboard, then past it into my email(output page), I want to see it interpret <h1>test</h1> into html view(large and bold fonts). Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I don't know but you can take a look here [getElementById from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930780/getelementbyid-from-another-page) and here [Thread: document.getElementById from another page?](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?67448-document-getElementById-from-another-page)

Comment: About the large and bold, i eddited the answer