# Locating a frame contained iframe from a sibling frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frames

My web page is made of 2 `frame`s with the `name` and `id` attributes set to "left" and "center".

I run a JS script in the left one to be able to locate/identify an `iframe` with `name` and `id` "monfrm" in the center frame.

Here is the JavaScript I have so far:

```
x = top.document.getElementById("center");
alert(x.src);   //fine
// ok up to here
y = x.getElementById("monfrm");  // attempting to locate my iframe within "center" frame & that's where it hurts
alert("left says" + y.width);   //eeh nothing
```

I'm probably getting old cos' it seems pitifully easy unless I missed a point.... :-)

Any light shed welcome

Thanks

Comment: Is  `width` a valid HTMLElement property? Maybe trying with `offsetWidth` could solve your problem.

Comment: Look on console. You'll have an error about getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `getElementById` to select within a `frame`/`iframe`, you need to call it on the frame's `contentWindow.document` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14451440):

```
document.getElementById('myframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById('x')
```

Given your code, you would want to set

```
y = x.contentWindow.document.getElementById("monfrm");
```

Comment: You guys are terrific , both comments led me to fix the issue thanks a lot

Comment: If your question has been answered, please consider marking the answer as accepted (checkmark on the left)  so the question can be closed. :)