# VBA - IE - certain element tags on the website not found with ie.document.all

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vba, internet-explorer

The website is:

http://www.midhudsonmlshomes.com/template38/nextpage.asp?mnu=191227

I can't get tags of some elements, especially the Find Now submit button with input tag. I must underline that it happens even if I set debug break point and give the website a minute to load before referring to these elements.

I used `ie.document.GetElementsByTagName("input")` but it haven't found the element in question, what's more it retrieved an empty collection, even though this input tag is not the only one on the page. I double checked it by printing `ie.document.all` collection elements, but there were no input tags.

I found a workaround to navigate directly through result pages like the one below, editing Seq=1 in a loop to for example Seq13 and on such result pages I can find all desired elements.

http://www.midhudsonmlshomes.com/template38/membersearch.asp?OrderId=19688&LanguageId=0&Seq=1

Still it bothers me why I was unable to get the elements I needed, can it be because of .asp?

Comment: That page uses an iframe, so you're looking in the wrong document for the inputs `ie.document.GetElementById("IFrameMain").document.GetElementsByTagName("input")` should give you what you expect

Comment: Thank You for suggestion, it helped me find a solution (the code is missing "contentwindow"). I tested the website with ?ie.document.GetElementById("IFrameMain").contentwindow.document.GetElementsByTagName("input").length and I'm getting all 3 input elements. The ultimate solution was in the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid