# Get data of a form in iframe before submit it with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Good day all, I have a complicate work to do. Lets try to explain:

I have a Basic web form I load inside an iframe in my web:

```
<form >
First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I need to "scan" the data BEFORE they submit it and then send it to an php file as post or get so I can read it from there. I need some javascript code to do this.

Is this even possible? Thanks you for your help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid This one should solve your Problem.