# Selenium WebDriver(Appium) - How to switch to IFrame using driver.ExecuteJavascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, webdriver, appium

I'm currently facing an issue with Appium automating a hybrid iOS application when trying to switch to an IFrame. Whilst I've been able to switch to my IFrame successfully on Android using:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iFrameElement);
```

There's a known issue with Appium in that this approach doesn't work on iOS due to an Appium bug. A suggested workaround was to use the method below to switch to the IFrame element.

```
driver.ExecuteJavascript()
```

I just was wondering if anyone knows how I'd go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pick element inside iframe using document.getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid)