# getElementsByName does not work inside nested HTML

Tags: html, getelementsbyname

I am trying to retreive data using document.getElementsByName but the function returns empty if my element is inside a nested HTML document. I am not sure if this is the reason but the fact is that right before the nested HTML the function works fine.

here is a simplification:

```
<html>
  ...
   <iframe name="contentFrame"> // getElementsByName can find this element
      <html>
         ...
           <input name="ship_no">   // getElementsByName  returns empty
         ...
      </html>
  ...
 </html>
```

I did some searching and couldn't find anything related. Can anyone think of a workaround for this problem?

Comment: it is because document loaded into an iframe is considered a separate one

Comment: _"Can anyone think of a workaround for this problem?"_ - how about, some basic research? https://www.google.com/search?q=getElementsByName%20access%20element%20inside%20iframe -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid

Answer (score 2):

An `iframe` is considered a different document from the current document.

First get the `iframe` and then get the `iframe`'s `contentDocument`.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

You can then call `innerDoc.getElementsByName`.