# Hide header of Sharepoint custom list displayed in iframe

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint-2013

I have a custom list from a different sharepoint site (still the same domain) that I would like to display on my work site without the header (at a minimum, but getting rid of the ribbon would be nice too).  I have attempted 4 methods without success listed below:

[1)](https://davidlozzi.com/2014/10/28/sharepoint-hiding-ribbon-and-more-with-isdlg/) I can't even get it to work on a normal page by adding ?isdlg=1 to the end of my url (ie ..allitems.aspx?isdlg=1)

[2)](https://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2011/09/23/hide-page-elements-sharepoint-dialog-box/) since I mostly work with SQL and not HTML I am sure I may have screwed up some of my tags.

```
<div class="ms-dlgFrameContainer">
<iframe width="1400" height="600" id="DlgFramee" class="ms-dlgFrame" frameborder="0" src="myurl.aspx">
<html class="ms-dialog">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.ms-dialog #titleAreaBox { display:none }
</style>`
```

[3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid) to hide the header of the page inside the iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myiframe1").contentWindow.document.getElementById("titlerow").style.display = "none"; </script>`
```

[4)](http://www.macaalay.com/2014/01/28/how-to-remove-sharepoint-2013-quick-launch-andor-top-link-bar/) Most promising.  When I add

```
<iframe id="myiframe1" src="myurl" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="1"></iframe>
<style>
#titleAreaBox { display: none }
</style>
```

in the same CEWP as my iframe, it removes the title area for current page and not the page in the iframe.  This exactly what I want except I want it to do that for the page inside the iframe.

[5)](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493775/Apply-CSS-styles-to-SharePoint-Web-parts) I did this as well even just trying to change header color but didn't notice any change.  I looked up the correct webpart ID.

```
<style type="text/css">
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .ms-WPHeader
{ background-color: pink; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try below jQuery script, I just hide `suiteBarTop` in demo.

```
<iframe id="myiframe" width="1400" height="600" id="DlgFramee" class="ms-dlgFrame" frameborder="0" src="/sites/tst/SitePages/Home.aspx"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#myiframe').load(function () {
                $(this).contents().find('#suiteBarTop').hide();
            });

        })        
    </script>
```

Comment: This was perfect! Sorry for the delay. I just changed sutebartop to the ribbon, title, and header ids and it worked perfectly!