# How Picture-in-Picture works for iframes

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, youtube, picture-in-picture

I've read a couple of documents (google searches) in working around Picture-in-Picture (PiP). It really says it is available only for video elements. (See reference: https://w3c.github.io/picture-in-picture)

Also looked into the code of PiP [extension](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/picture-in-picture-chrome-extension/blob/master/src/script.js) created by chrome
You can see from the code here that it finds the "largest" video element.

My question is, how did they make it work in YouTube embedded videos? It is inside an iframe, right?
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14451440/2955091) approach in order to get the video inside the iframe. It will not work because of cross origin policy and it is clear that this is not the approach they used in the extension.

Someone know what's behind all this or someone else experiencing the same?