# Is there a way to select via CSS elements inside UMAP iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, iframe, selector

I am displaying a uMap map in my website. Here it is :

```
<iframe id="umapiframe" class="iframe-umap" width="100%" height="300px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="//umap.openstreetmap.fr/fr/map/agroavenir_665397?scaleControl=false&miniMap=false&scrollWheelZoom=false&zoomControl=true&allowEdit=false&moreControl=true&searchControl=null&tilelayersControl=null&embedControl=null&datalayersControl=true&onLoadPanel=none&captionBar=false"></iframe>
```

It actually looks pretty nice, except I really want to change some CSS inside. Here, I want to replace the navigation buttons to the corner bottom/right except the top/left :

[image]

As you can see, in the second picture, I've been able to modify localy the CSS just to see a potential result, and it's actually exactly what I want !

But the element is actually inside an iframe document, and through that, I can't reach the element I want to reach in my css file.

[image]

I am a bit frustrated to not be able to make permanent this kind of things, displaying perfectly in front of me...

Is there a way to reach via CSS selector the inside of this iframe ? Or, through an other way, moving those elements in the other corner ?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* get an element inside an iframe using this code:

```
const iframe = document.querySelector(/**iframe selector**/)
iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector(/**element selector**/)
```

Then style it with js.

Related questions:

[How to pick element inside iframe using document.getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid)

[Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, with CSS you can select only classes in the same document and iframe is a whole new document, so the answer would be that you can't.
Maybe you can try to target it with javascript.

Code example:

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.body.querySelector('#some-element').style.background-color = 'red';
```

Source: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1050889