# Controlling Font of PDF Displayed in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a PDF file in browser and control the font used in the PDF. For example, I should be able increase and decrease the font size.

Currently, I am using an `<object>` element to display the PDF. To fetch this PDF I am making an HTTP request to the server and setting the URL attribute of the `<object>` element. But this does not provide much ability to control the content of PDF document like increase and decrease the font size.

How can I control the font (increase and decrease) of a displayed PDF in Object tag? is there some way to do it via javascript?

My sample code is here:

```
<object width="auto"
        height="auto"
        classid="clsid:19DDC62D-DB2C-48BA-88F8-9678DCBE0257"
        url="http://test.net/?doc_id=1212"/>
```

Comment: Achieve what using JavaScript?  Parse and display a PDF?  Or create an object tag dynamically?

Comment: "But it does not provide much ability to control the content of pdf document." what are you talking about ? what do you want to control?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798745/how-to-get-html-elements-from-an-object-tag?rq=1

Comment: @RachelGallen... your link seems nothing like the question he's asking, and it doesn't even have an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
http://pdfobject.com/

"PDFObject embeds PDF files into HTML documents"

You can use their generator http://pdfobject.com/generator.php to optimize the look and feel of the embeded pdf.

Comment: this looks great. does this also give ability by which i can change the text font of pdf after converting in to HTML?