# Reach <body>'s scrollTop element of <embed>'ed html document

Tags: javascript

As the title says I cant reach the scrollTop element of `<body>` inside my `<embed>`'ed html file.
Im trying to implement a scrollTop button on my index page which loads html documents via js.

```
content.innerHTML = "<embed id='object' onscroll='scrollFunction()' width='100%' height='100%' src='" + documentName + "'></embed>'";
```

I tried things like `document.getElementById("object").body.scrollTop = 0;`

The result is obviously an exception in the console or constantly `scrollTop = 0` if I let the .body out and log `document.getElementById("object").scrollTop`
(before setting it to 0)

EDIT:

I changed `<embed src=></embed>` to `<object data=></object>`
and

```
var object = document.getElementById("object");
var htmlDocument = object.contentDocument;
htmlDocument.body.scrollTop = 0;
```

The console exception is:
 `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`
Idk whats goin on

Comment: You need to access the `document` of the page displayed inside the object element first of all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28754598/10283047

Comment: @misorude I made an EDIT

Comment: Well if the content inside the object is loaded from a different domain, then you of course have no JavaScript access to it at all - keyword Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @misorude but the embeded document is just in a subfolder.. everything is on my domain

Comment: When did you execute the code you have shown? Did you wait for the document embedded inside the object to finish loading?

Comment: @misorude No the document finished loading. Im using this as a back to top button on my index sidebar for my embeded page instead of an buttton on every page i embed